# Navicat for MySQL - How to copy fields name quickly?

Tags: mysql, database, navicat

In phpMyAdmin, I can highlight any fields name quickly to copy and paste it in the script (eg: php files)

How do I do same process in Navicat?

Answer (score 6):

Method 1:
Right click on the table name. Click "Design Table". In the columns tab, click column name header or use Ctrl/Shift to multi-select the fields you need to copy and Ctrl+C.

Method 2:
After 3 years, upon more usage of the software I found this:
In the result grid of any query, highlight one whole row, or only the columns you want (with Ctrl/Shift key pressed to multi-select), right click on highlighted area. In the context menu select 
**Copy as** > **Tab-split field name**

Mind that my software is in Chinese so I translated it. Your GUI may look different but you get the point. Also the option is there for Navicat Premium. I don't know if other editions have it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful.

Comment: @TuralAsgar I added another method if you're interested :)

Comment: It is also very helpful and I need both context. 1st one does by putting new line, second one tab separated. Thank you very much!